# Random int while loop generating similar results every iteration

Tags: c#

I am trying to print out 2 random numbers between a range of 1-6 ( such as "1, 5", "4,3" ).
I want to print this 5 times.

The code below appears to be working, except that most of the time all 5 prints have the same result, such as:

1,4
1,4
1,4
1,4
1,4

Now, this is not always as the case as the results will vary at times, but I am wondering if perhaps I can improve this code. Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this code better fit the desired output?

```
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomInt = random.Next(1, 6);
        int randomInt2 = random.Next(1, 6);

        int i = 0;

        while (i <= 4)
        {                              
            Console.WriteLine(randomInt.ToString() + ", " + randomInt2.ToString());
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: You appear to be expecting `randomInt` to change each time you read it. It's just an `int`... a value. You're not saying "Call this method each time you want to read from this variable" - that's not how variables work in C#.

Comment: What line of code do you expect to cause the numbers to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assigned random values before your while loop instead of inside while loop!!!

Make it

```
    Random random = new Random();

    int i = 0;

    while (i <= 4)
    {                              
        int randomInt = random.Next(1, 6);
        int randomInt2 = random.Next(1, 6);
        Console.WriteLine(randomInt.ToString() + ", " + randomInt2.ToString());
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `random.Next()` for each iteration of the loop

Currently you are just printing the 2 same initial random values in the loop